# Import csv file to 3 tables with foreign and primary keys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, import, foreign-keys, mariadb

I need some help with importing Excel table (`.csv`) to MySQL database with foreign key.

The MySQL tables are:

**tests** table

```
  test_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  patient_ID INT DEFAULT NULL FOREIGN KEY (patient.id)
  test_type_ID INT DEFAULT NULL FOREIGN KEY (tests_types.id)
  result DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL
  comment VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
```

**tests_types** table

```
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  rf_nmu_ID INT DEFAULT NULL,
  loinc_od INT DEFAULT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  test_sourcename VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
```

**patient** table

```
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Source `.csv` contains:

- `p_id` column for `patient_ID` field (first column with `1`,`2`,`3`,`4` etc.)
- Columns with tests values for each `p_id` for each test type (`t1`,`t2`,`t3`,`t4`, etc)
- (`t1`,`t2`,`t3`,`t4`, etc) are values for foreign key field `test_type_ID` in `tests` table, linked to `ID` primary key field in `tests_types` table
- numeric values for `result` field in `tests` table

Source `.csv`:

+--------+-----------------------+

| p_id |  t1  |  t2  |   t3  |  t4 |

+--------+-----+-----+------+----+

| 1      | 123 | 4,4 | 0,83 | 37 |

+--------+-----+-----+------+----+

| 2      | 124 | 4,3 | 0,86 | 36 |

+--------+-----+-----+------+----+

| 3      | 146 | 4,4 | 0,99 | 44 |

+--------+-----+-----+------+----+

| 4      | 96  | 3,5 | 0,82 | 30 |

+--------+-----+-----+------+----+

| 5      | 116 | 4   | 0,87 | 38 |

+--------------------------------+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this question I've understood that I could **unpivot columns** in Excel Power Questions making table 1D from 2D as you can see at this link:

- [Unpivot columns (Power Query)](https://support.office.com/en-my/article/Unpivot-columns-Power-Query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098?ui=en-US&rs=en-MY&ad=MY) on Microsoft Office support site

After transforming my source `.csv` table from 2D to 1D I've got:

+--------+---------+-------+

| pat_id | test_id | value |

+--------+---------+-------+

| 1      | 1       | 123   |

+--------+---------+-------+

| 1      | 2       | 4,4   |

+--------+---------+-------+

| 1      | 3       | 0,83  |

+--------+---------+-------+

| 1      | 4       | 37    |

+--------+---------+-------+

| 1      | 5       |   7    |

+--------+---------+-------+

and this table I've imported to my `tests` table and now it's all works!